# "Send an Email" button not visible on Opportunity level

Tags: opportunity, send-an-email

How do I get the delivered "Send an Email" button to show up on the opportunity header level?  The "Send an Email" button *does* show up on the activity history related list, just not at the opportunity header level.

[image: send_an_email_opp]

[image]

I have also ensured that

- my profile has the ability to send an email
- my email deliverability is set to send all emails

Comment: The actual opp screen uses a different page layout than the screenshot posted above, but the problem does exist for the other layout as well.

Comment: Send emailfrom Activity is a native functionality. I don't think Salesforce provide this in Opportunity you need to manually implement this.

Comment: Ok - so I guess I'm assuming this is just some non-functional stuff that is automatically injected into each dev org.